# How to upload multiple files to S3 using a presigned URL and restrict to a single folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Suppose you want to upload multiple files into a directory `/upload` using a presigned URL to Amazon S3.

How to upload multiple files with a single presigned URL?

How to restrict uploads to a certain folder?

Comment: Using a REST `PUT` upload, or a browser-based `POST` upload?

Comment: Using a browser-based javascript HTTP call. Could be either `PUT` or `POST`.

Answer (score 3):

Objects can be uploaded to private Buckets by using an HTTP POST. It includes parameters to specify the destination, such as a specific subdirectory. However, this method only supports one object at a time.

See: [Browser-Based Uploads Using POST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html)